# Filtrar strings bajo una condición usando listas por comprensión

Tags: python, lista

Estoy intentado hacer un ejercicio de Python en el que se plantea mediante el uso de listas por comprensión y a partir de una lista dada que contenga una serie de strings, retornar aquellos cuya cantidad de palabras contenidas en el string sea mayor a una condición. En este caso mayor a 2.

Ejemplo de lista definida por el ejercicio:

```
books_list = ['Los premios', 'Rayuela', '62 modelo de armar',
              'Libro de Manuel', 'Divertimento', 'El examen',
              'Bestiario', 'Final del juego', 'Las armas secretas',
              'Todos los fuegos el fuego', 'Octaedro',
              'Historias de cronopios y de famas', 'Casa tomada']
```

Comment: "lo que debo hacer es coger aquellas palabras de la lista que sean menores de 2" Menos a 2 letras? O te refieres a las cadenas que contengan menos de 2 palabras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad puede usar el método `len()` spliteando el string mediante: `split()`: un método perteneciente a cada objeto str. Si deseas hacerlo por listas de comprensión entonces quedaría:

```
mayores_a_dos = [s for s in books_list if len(s.split()) > 2]
```

El resultado será una lista qu contenga:

['62 modelo de armar',
'Libro de Manuel',
'Final del juego',
'Las armas secretas',
'Todos los fuegos el fuego',
'Historias de cronopios y de famas']

Comment: Muchas gracias, es perfecta la solucion. espero poder coger nivel pronto y ayudar a otras personas como tu me has ayudado.

Comment: Buenas, estoy intentando escribir el código que me has pllanteado en Repl.it y no se pq no me funciona, ayer en jupiter me fue son problema. sabes si puede ser pq split no esta como funcion y necesito instalar algun paquete?. queria añadirte una imagen pero no veo la opcion...

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no sea la manera más "fancy" de ponerlo, creo que así se entiende bastante bien! Te dejo comentado por si quieres que sean >2 o <=2 la cantidad de palabras!

```
books_list = ['Los premios', 'Rayuela', '62 modelo de armar',
              'Libro de Manuel', 'Divertimento', 'El examen',
              'Bestiario', 'Final del juego', 'Las armas secretas',
              'Todos los fuegos el fuego', 'Octaedro',
              'Historias de cronopios y de famas', 'Casa tomada']

# Creamos una lista que usaremos para guardar lo que queramos
menores = []   


for books in books_list:
    # De cada elemento, separamos por espacios
        # "Los premios" ahora es ["los", "premios"], ["62", "modelo", "de", "armar"]
        # Contamos la longitud de cada lista (2 en el primer caso, 4 en el segundo)
    if len(books.split())<=2:
    #if len(books.split())>2:
        menores.append(books)
print("final")
print(menores)
```

> ['Los premios', 'Rayuela', 'Divertimento', 'El examen', 'Bestiario', 'Octaedro', 'Casa tomada']

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. funciona perfectamente.

Comment: de nada! Si la has encontrado útil, vótala de manera positiva! @JDS